# How to model measures that depend on the underlying substance

Tags: oop, smalltalk

I'm using the [Aconcagua](http://sdmeta.gforge.inria.fr/Teaching/CoursAnnecy/0506-M1-COO/aconcagua-p292-wilkinson.pdf) measurement library in [Pharo](http://pharo.org). I've had a lot of success using it to model things like days and kilometers, but have encountered an interesting problem where converting between units requires information on the underlying substance being measured. The formula for expressing the amount of a substance in air in parts per million, given the amount in milligrams per cubic meter is:

[image: PPM = mg/m^3 x 24.45 / molecularWeight]; where `mw` is the molecular weight of the material.

I'm envisioning usage like:

`tlvCO := carbonMonoxide tlv. "returns the Threshold limit Value as 29 mg/m3"
...
tlvCO convertTo: PPM "where PPM is an Aconcagua unit"`

The problem is that, while the examples I've seen of measurements in Aconcagua are contain in themselves all the info you need for conversion, in this case, you have to know the molecular weight of the underlying substance being measured. Thus `mg/m3 -> ppm` is not inherently meaningful. A properly formed question would be `mg/m3 of ammonia -> ppm`.

My instinct is to either:

1. create a new class like `MaterialQuantity` which has a material and a measure, or
2. create a special unit subclass that has a material

But I'm not 100% sold and would like some input...

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that molecular weight is part of the unit, but part of a calculation, like the 24.45 (which is not clear, but it seems that is an average you consider for air molecular mass).

I am not sure that ppm is a unit that you can convert to a density unit, because they belong in different domains.

Comment: The problem is that they are used interchangeably in practice, so a reference book might give you mg/m3 which you then have to convert to ppm to line up with your detector, so if you say `carbonMonoxide tlv`, which gives you the Threshold limit Value as 29 mg/m3, I think for the model to make sense you have to be able to say `carbonMonoxide tlv convertTo: PPM`

Comment: Yes, I understand the problem, but I think is more than a unit conversion.
Note that PPM is not enough to define a unit, you should need to have a unit for PPM on air, another for PPM on water, PPM on crude oil and so on.
It is like trying to convert volume to weight. You can do it, given the density, but that does not mean that you can convert weight units to volume units.

Answer (score 0):

As far as i understand, you need to reify tlv as a compound unit or formula, which you can ask for the element. Then you could simply do something like [:tlv | tlv * ( 24.45 / tlv element) ]